# Should thermal pads be connected to GND or not?

Tags: surface-mount, power-dissipation

I'm creating a footprint for the [TPS2141](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2141.pdf) (LDO and current limiter) and I wonder if the thermal pad should be connected to the GND plane or if thats a bad idea? Should it just have its own copper zone that´s not connected to anything?

Thermally it should be very beneficial to connect it to the ground plane I guess.

Comment: This depends on the part.  Many should be connected to ground, a few are specific that they should *not* be.  When things are unclear, also see if you can find a reference design or board layout guidance - you have a TI part, they especially tend to publish such things.

Comment: The datasheet simply shows a thermal pad and is silent on whether it is in fact ground. I would err on the side of caution and *not* connect it to ground although my first port of call would be TI support / forums for clarification.

Comment: If a multi-layer board, could thermally stitch to an inner layer and run that physically under or over power planes, allowing some thermal transfer via conduction while being galvanically isolated. Prepreg tends to be quite thin; would not try that across core material (usually thicker.)

Comment: Thanks for the info people, will check with TI support 

Comment: if the region must be isolated, then, as 'rdtsc' explains, you must design the PCB stackup to effectively transfer heat to large planes

Comment: Given the part has only 5v and ground supplies, it's likely that the pad can be grounded. I've only ever got into trouble grounding the pad of dual rail op-amp (boy did the ordure hit the ventilation device over that one) which needed to be -ve rail or isolated. However, why guess when you can check with TI. Their general powerpad slma002 document is no help, saying only that you can find out what you can connect the pad to from the part datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole page in the datasheet dedicated to the thermal pad, which specifies handling as in the document at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slma002h/slma002h.pdf

That document specifies "Check the respective product data sheet to verify which signal, power, or ground plane the device should be soldered to"

Given the absence of handling in the product data sheet, I would contact TI if this is important.  I would also choose not to design around that part if I couldn't get an authoritative answer, in writing, and move on to the next part that would suit my needs.

Update:  It looks like https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slma004b/slma004b.pdf now specifies that the thermal pads can be connected to the ground plane.  Still wishy washy enough to merit a check with TI